# ошибка Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Tags: python

Делаю бота на pyrogram, столкнулся с неправильным выполнением кода: Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

```
import time
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QTextEdit, QPushButton
from PyQt6.QtGui import QTextCursor
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from test1 import open_file


class UserBot(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Создание экземпляра клиента
        api_id = ''
        api_hash = ''
        session_name = '.session'
        self.client = Client(session_name, api_id, api_hash)
        self.client.start()

        # Инициализация интерфейса пользователя
        self.setWindowTitle("User Bot")
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.log_area = QTextEdit()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.log_area)

        self.start_button = QPushButton("Start")
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.start_bot)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.start_button)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def write_log(self, text):
            self.log_area.append(text)
            self.log_area.moveCursor(QTextCursor.End)

    def start_bot(self):
            # Присоединение к чатам
            self.write_log("Joining chats...")

            @self.client.on_message(filters.chat)
            def on_message(client, message):
                self.write_log(f"Joined chat: {message.chat.title}")
            # Рассылка сообщений
            self.write_log("Sending messages...")
            chats = open_file('channels.txt')
            message = "Hello, everyone!"
            interval = 5 # Интервал между сообщениями (в секундах)
            timer = QTimer(self)
            timer.timeout.connect(lambda: self.send_messages(chats, message))
            timer.start(interval * 1000) # QTimer работает в миллисекундах

    def send_messages(self, chats, message):
        for chat in chats:
            try:
                self.client.send_message(chat.id, message)
                self.write_log(f"Message sent to chat: {chat.title}")
            except Exception as e:
                self.write_log(f"Failed to send message to chat: {chat.title}. Error: {e}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    user_bot = UserBot()
    user_bot.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Алексей, 1. чтобы получить реальную ошибку - запустите ваше приложение в консоли/терминале/CMD. 2. В строке `@self.client.on_message(filters.chat)` - первый символ, это что?

Comment: запустил через cmd: C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram bot>TEST.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram bot\TEST.py", line 2, in <module>
    import PyQt6
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt6'. Говорит, что нет библиотеки, но она установлена

Comment: Алексей, 1. Установлена где, в виртуальном окружении? 2. В строке `@self.client.on_message(filters.chat)` - первый символ, это что?

Comment: это декоратор, если честно не понимаю зачем он там нужен(эту часть кода выдала gpt), библиотека установлена через PyCharm, да и вообще только в нем работаю